# Numbered letters

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I've been looking for a while now, for something I think is very basic. How can I use, for instance, "v0" with the 0 smaller next to the v.

Like this:

[image]

I can't find it, mainly because I'm not sure what to call it.

Comment: Simply $v_0$. Very basic, indeed.

Comment: `$v_{0}$`? Reading a basic guide is recommended; go to http://ctan.org and type `lshort` in the search box, you'll get a list of a good introductory guide in several languages.

Comment: is this really about subscripts, or about the use of "old style" numerals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're thinking of typesetting material in *subscript* position, you can do so as follows, in TeX's math mode:

```
$v_{0}$
```

Conversely, to typeset material in *superscript* position, you can do so (again in TeX's math mode) as follows:

```
$a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}$
```

To familiarize yourself some more with LaTeX and, in particular, its ways of handling the typesetting of math material, you may want to study Chapter 3 of Tobias Oetiker's "[Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf)".

Answer (score 2):

By default the subscript uses `\scriptstyle`, so if you need a smaller subscript then use `\scriptscriptstyle` as shown in the given image below.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
$v_0$ or $v_{\scriptstyle 0}$ or $v_{\scriptscriptstyle 0}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend:

- `\(v_0\)` or `\(v_{12}\)` in continuous text (named `inline math` mode)
- `\begin{equation} v_0 \end{equation}` for standalone equations (named `displaymath` mode).